# Material UI with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to figure out how to use Material UI with React.

I've installed the module and have tried to create a button component.

I have:

Button.js

```
import React from 'react';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';

const style = {
  margin: 12,  
};

const MyButton = () => (
    <div>
        <FlatButton  />


    </div>
);

export default MyButton;
```

Now, I'm trying to use the Button with inputs for my specific element.

In my Landing.js component, I have:

```
import React from 'react';
import MyButton from './materialui/Button.js';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';

const Landing = () => (

  <div className="hero">
    Projects
    <p className="tagline">Create project</p>
    <MuiThemeProvider>
      <MyButton
        secondary={true}
        backgroundColor="$navy"
        hoverColor="$green"
        label="GET STARTED"

      />
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  </div>

);

export default Landing;
```

However, when I try this I get an error that says:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Required prop label or children or icon was
>   not specified in FlatButton.

If I put a label in the button, then I'll need to make a different button every time I want to change the label. Is there a way I can define the styling and label in the component that I want to use the button on? The example on Material UI seems to show the button being used in this way, but I can't see what's missing to get it setup to work.

Comment: If you're just starting out with material-ui, you should [switch to v1](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui#should-i-start-with-v1-beta) before you get too far into your project. v0 is nominally the stable version but that should change in the next few weeks, so it's recommended all new projects go with v1 instead.

Comment: Thanks @JulesDupont - have you found any tutorials on how to customise it? I can't make sense of the documentation.

Comment: What do you mean by customize? Changing the themes or applying styling to individual components?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can define the styling and label in the component
>   that I want to use the button on?

Yes you can, issue is you are passing the values in props from `Landing` component, but not using inside MyButton component. See whatever value you pass from parent in props will not get applied directly.

Write it like this:

```
const MyButton = props => (
    <div>
        <FlatButton  {...props} />
    </div>
);
```

Now all the values that you pass from parent will get passed to `FlatButton`.

**Note:**

By `{...props}` all the props values will get passed to FlatButton, but if you want to pass some specific not all then use destructuring and take out those values and then pass.

Like this:

```
const MyButton = props => {
    const {label, backgroundColor, hoverColor, secondary=false} = props;
    return <div>
        <FlatButton  {...{label, backgroundColor, hoverColor, secondary}} /> 
    </div>
};
```

Comment: thank you. I tried this, but get an error that says: Warning: Failed prop type: Required prop label or children or icon was not specified in FlatButton. There must be something I'm missing. Do you know where I can find detailed examples of how this works?

Comment: When I try your second example, I get an error that says: warning.js:33 Warning: Unknown props `a`, `b`, `c` on <button> tag. Remove these props from the element

Comment: are you passing all values from parent in `MyButton` (exactly same way as you showed in ques), from all the places? second way was a example, you were supposed to replace a.b.c with the actual key name (that you are passing from parent component)

Comment: Yes - everything in the post is exactly from the code. I tried variations on the abc to use exact names from material UI and from props.materialUIexactname. Neither worked. I can't find an example that works.

Comment: Thanks @Mayank for trying to help me, I wish I could make sense of this. When I try to use the example you've given me, I get errors that say: Warning: Unknown props `backgroundColor`, `hoverColor`, `secondary` on <button> tag. Remove these props from the element. For details, see https://reactjs.org/warnings/unknown-prop.html and Failed prop type: The prop `children` is marked as required in `Button`, but its value is `undefined`. I'm reading the links explaining, but I can't make sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

I see you still having issues. So posting in detail with easy way to make you understand better. The other answer also perfectly alright if you understand spread operator. This is another way of doing.

The reason you see this warning. BTW it’s not an error but thery are warnings:)

### Warning: Failed prop type: Required prop label or children or icon was not specified in FlatButton.

because, FlatButton expects at least one prop i.e., label/childern/icon but you have called  without a single prop. So we should pass label prop to FlatButton to see name on the button for example. [check here](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/flat-button) for more details.

Now, you are already passing right props to MyButton component but the problem is that you are not receiving those props in MyComponent and pass it to FlatButton. I would recommend you to receive props in MyButton and pass it to FlatButton.

I cleaned up your code please take a look

Receiving props and passing it to FlatButton

```
import React from 'react';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';

const style = {
  margin: 12,  
};

const MyButton = (props) => (
    <div>
        <FlatButton  label={props.label} backgroundColor={props.backgroundColor} hoverColor={props.hoverColor} secondary={props.secondary}/>
    </div>
);

export default MyButton;
```